# Statistical methods for comparing performance of ML algorithms on unevenly distributed datasets

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, algorithms

Having multiple ML algorithms for outlier/anomaly detection and even more datasets with always two classes (which are intentionally distributed unevenly), I did cross-validation tests for each model and dataset. From all of the above, I've collected accuracy scores that somehow give viable results, but I would like to make them 'more grounded' in sound statistical tests;

What approach would you use to (hopefully) reject the null hypothesis that 'algorithms in general performed better in the bigger of unevenly distributed groups'?
Thank you

Comment: For reproducibility purpose, please provide an toy dataset to clarify your question.